# Published .aspx only shows plain html

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Today i made a quick template for a landingpage and wanted to test it on my webhotel. I have never actually  published a website on a webhotel before, but the initial process in asp.net was pretty flawless. 
The way i got my webpage onto the server, was by publishing my project and transferring it to my server on a FTP connection.

However, when i open my up my webpage, it only shows the html code, which is really weird. .

```
http://bkrt.dk/Index.aspx
```

What may i have done wrong, and How do i solve this issue?

Comment: Framework converts aspx pages to raw html, thats how world works my friend.

Comment: You have a UNIX environment  - is this capable to run asp.net ? ask your provider

Comment: you hit the nail @Aristos

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my webhotel doesnt support .aspx, but only php! 
- Solution is that i either change webhotel, or do a full convertion to html, which seems to be no option. I will therefore look for a webhotel with asp.net support.